# swift: difference between an 2d array and a dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swift3

I kinda get confused between the two. I know a dictionary is initialized like:

```
var Dictionary=[Int:Int]
```

and is like `[1:100,2:150]` or `[1:"cat",2:"dog"]`.

But I'm kinda of confused about 2d arrays. I think it is initialized like:

```
var Arr=[Int[Int]]()
```

and looks like `[[1,4],[5,3]]` and It should have an `x` and `y` coordinate.

I was wondering if the two are interchangeable and which would work best when making this grid? And if I wanted to store information at coordinate `[2,1]=6` which should I use?

```
 [0,1,0,0]
 [0,1,1,0]
 [1,0,0,1]
```

Comment: **Array** is an **ordered** collection type containing values accessible by index, **Dictionary** is an **unordered** collection type containing key/value pairs accessible by key.

Comment: briefly, you can imagine the array as an _martix_ and the dictionary as a _tree_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't get confused by the fact that both arrays and dictionaries use `[ ]` symbols for their literals. The two are completely different. a dictionary is used when you have a set of keys and each key has an associated value. A 2d array is essentially a matrix of values.

For your little matrix you want a 2d array. You can create and initialize a 2d array like this:

```
var matrix : [[Int]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: 10), count: 10)
```

This would create a 10x10 matrix filled with zeros. To set a value you can do:

```
matrix[x][y] = 6
```

as long as `x` is `0` to `rows - 1` and `y` is `0` to `columns - 1`.

Or read a value like:

```
let value = matrix[x][y]
```

Comment: Could you add an example of how *exactly* dictionaries would work just like you did for the 2d arrays?

Comment: @LinusG. Why? There are countless examples of dictionaries. And a dictionary doesn't apply to the matrix.

Comment: I just thought having a direct comparison would be neat :)

Comment: @LinusG. There is no direct comparison since you wouldn't use a dictionary for this. It has a completely different use unrelated to the OP's needs.